# gehören’s past participle

Tags: morphology

Duden says that *gehören* is a weak verb. Therefore its past participle should be formed by adding “ge” to the onset and (e)t to the end of the verbal stem. Following this rule, I expected the past participle to be **gegehört*; but it is *gehört*.

What has happened here? Is there a rule that erases one of the “ge”s when we have repeated ge?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Duden says that gehören is a weak verb. Therefore its past participle should be formed by adding “ge” to the onset.

**NO.** Someone taught you a wrong rule. Forget it immediately.

The correct rule is that verbs with an inseparable prefix don't get a *ge-* in their Partizip II. This rule applies to both weak and strong verbs. Compare for example strong *laufen*:

- laufen, es läuft, es lief, es ist gelaufen
- einlaufen, es läuft ein, es lief ein, es ist eingelaufen
- verlaufen, es verläuft, es verlief, es ist verlaufen

and weak *kaufen*:

- kaufen, es kauft, es kaufte, es hat gekauft
- einkaufen, es kauft ein, es kaufte ein, es hat eingekauft
- verkaufen, es verkauft, es verkaufte, es hat verkauft

And this is the same for *gehören*, as *ge-* is also an inseparable prefix.

- gehören, es gehört, es gehörte, es hat gehört

Don't confuse the *ge-* and *gegen-* prefixes though:

- gegensteuern, es steuert gegen, es steuerte gegen, es hat gegen**ge**steuert

---

Please note there's another class “loan verbs on -ieren” that is special as well:

- aktivieren, es aktiviert, es aktivierte, es hat aktiviert
- rasieren, es rasiert, es rasierte, es hat rasiert
- musizieren, es musiziert, es musizierte, es hat musiziert
- abmontieren, es montiert ab, es montierte ab, es hat abmontiert
- … (tons more)

Those verbs feature no *ge-* in their Partizip II regardless whether there is a prefix or not.

Oh, and to drive you nuts there are some native Germanic verbs on *-ieren*. Those follow the general prefix rule:

- frieren, es friert, es fror, es hat gefroren
- schmieren, es schmiert, es schmierte, es hat geschmiert
- abschmieren, es schmiert ab, es schmierte ab, es hat abgeschmiert
- stieren, es stiert, es stierte, es hat gestiert
- verlieren, es verliert, es verlor, es hat verloren
- … (some more)

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarifying response. Now I see. Thanks.

Comment: There is even a play on words: "Ö1 [a radio station] gehört gehört", meaning "should be listened to".

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume a rule like the following.

> Past participles of **weak** verbs are formed with **ge-** and **-(e)t**.

The thing that is specific to weak verbs is the ending *-(e)t*. Strong verbs also get the prefix *ge-*. The rule is correct, but leaves out that *ge-* does only appear in front of stressed syllables.

First syllable stressed:

> 'suchen − ge'sucht
> 'zieren - ge'ziert
> 'halten − ge'halten
> 'bieten − ge'boten

First syllable unstressed:

> ver'suchen − ver'sucht
> spa'zieren − spa'ziert
> ver'halten − ver'halten
> ge'bieten − ge'boten

As the examples show, it's not about the repetition of *ge-*, it's that *ge-* is unstressed.

Examples for unstressed prefixes are *be-, ent-, ge-, er-, ver-, zer-*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your interesting point. It was interesting indeed to see the interplay between Phonology and Morphology. Thanks!